# Showing one row. Need to show it in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to figure out how to use this in a loop. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "some_user", "password");

if (!$conn) {
echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("some_db")) {
echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT favid FROM  ajaxfavourites";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row["favid"];

}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Currently it displays results as:

```
116677889922
```

I need them to show them as (the way they are displayed in DB):

```
1166
7788
9922
```

PS I am aware that this function is deprecated, I am just trying to fix one of my older sites.

Comment: Add a <br> tag to test: echo $row["favid"].'<br>';

Comment: Good to hear that my answer is helpful. If you think my answer is correct, will you make it the [Right Answer], rather than doing up-vote?

Answer (score 0):

choose One of these ways:

```
echo $row["favid"]."<br>";

echo $row["favid"]."\n";

echo $row["favid"].PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row["favid"];
echo "\r\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo the value with `'<br/>'` or `'<p>'` like following:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row["favid"] . '<br/>';

}
```

OR

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo '<p>' . $row["favid"] . '</p>';

}
```

Also you can just put all favid into array and then in another loop, can customize how to show them, like following:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$ids[] = $row["favid"];

}

foreach($ids AS $idv) {
echo '<p>' . $idv . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted. Can't upvote it since I don't have enough reputation.